# django model reference to own attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models

When i create a Django model i want to set the primary_key/ID to a combination of 2 attributes of this Model.

Example model:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="{}-{}".format(name, date) primary_key=True)
```

But he is saving the Model and not the values:

```
 field=models.CharField(default='<django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey>-<django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField>', max_length=100, primary_key=True, serialize=False),
```

I know that name and date *are* a model in this context, but "self." is not working and i can't find a Django function to get the actual values instead.

**It should work like this:**

Input:

```
testmodel = Example(name="foo", date=datetime.now())  
testmodel.save()
```

testmodel-id should look something like this "foo-2020-12-11..."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. Because these values are initialized at the making of an object. What you can do is to make your own class method to initialize these values.

```
class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    # In User class declaration


    @classmethod
    def create(cls,name, date):
        return cls(name=name, date=date, id="{}-{}".format(name,date))
```

And Use it like this outside the class

```
p = Example.create("Fred", "11-12-2020")
```